# How to write expect snippet in bash script to run remote command?

Tags: bash, expect

Currently I am running this script to print directories on a remote box but I am not sure this code is working.

```
#!/bin/bash

PWD="test123"
ip="10.9.8.38"
user=$1
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no $user@$ip df -h
expect "*assword:"
send "$PWD\n"
interact
EOD
```

Comment: Hope this helps: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/

Answer (score 2):

`expect` spawns a new sub-shell, hence your local `bash` variables lose their scope, one way to achieve this is to `export` your variables to make it available for the sub-shell. Use the [`Tcl env`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/tclvars.htm#M4) built-in to import such variables in your script.

```
#!/bin/bash

export pwdir="test123"
export ip="10.9.8.38"
export user=$1
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no "$env(user)"@"$env(ip)" df -h
expect "*assword:"
send "$env(pwdir)\n"
interact
EOD
```

(Or) If you are not interested in using an `expect` script directly with a `#!/usr/bin/expect` she-bang, you can do something like

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set pwdir [lindex $argv 0];
set ip [lindex $argv 1];
set user [lindex $argv 2];
spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no $user@$ip df -h
expect "*assword:"
send "$pwdir\n"
interact
```

and run the script as

```
./script.exp "test123" "10.9.8.38" "johndoe"
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion in my script I added sleep 2 after send "$PWD\n" and it worked. Now it priting output, but I am not able to grep it or use it in my local box.

Comment: @sandy_ws: If this solution worked, you can upvote/accept it and mark it resolved. You can raise your question in another post (or) give more details on what is not working